# Windows 8.1 - faulting application name: skydrive.exe

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I get this error several times per hour. I have a fresh (not upgrade) install of 8.1 professional. I miss my Skydrive from 8.0 :(

> Faulting application name: skydrive.exe, version: 6.3.9600.16412, time
>   stamp: 0x5243d370 Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0,
>   time stamp: 0x00000000 Exception code: 0x00000000 Fault offset:
>   0x0000000000000000 Faulting process id: 0x3dd0 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01cedff2ecb5c092 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Windows\System32\skydrive.exe Faulting module path: unknown Report
>   Id: 5db8b610-4be6-11e3-8278-24fd5200a9f2 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Have you installed all available updates?

Comment: I assume this is the `RTM` build instead of the `Preview` build.

Comment: I saw several skdrive crashes, so the best option is to phone the MS support and open a support case.

Comment: Yes, all available updates are installed. Yes, RTM.